# Why are classes considered reference types?

Tags: java

I am a beginner programmer and have a question. My book says classes are examples of references types and I am a little confused by this. I know their objects created from them certainly would be, but why would the class itself be a reference type?

Comment: It's a reference **type**. Meaning that is the name of the kind of object (I think). For example: `Person p = new Person();`. The type of `p` is `Person` because the name of the class is `Person`. However, it is possible that I am dead wrong, so don't take my word for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know their objects created from them certainly would be, but why would the class itself be a reference type?

Objects created from classes are reference objects, while classes themselves are reference types.

However, classes themselves have a run-time representation presented to programmers in the form of an instance of a class called `Class`. This makes classes reference objects, in addition to being reference types.